What is the functional difference between all the DOSBox variants?
Looking to virtualise a DOS system for software research purposes, I've come across a number of solutions. While I understand the difference between the DOSBoxes and emulators like Bochs or 86Box or whatever, I'm struggling to find a concise answer to the relationship and differences between the DOSBoxes themselves. The ones that I've seen thus far are:

DOSBox (the vanilla?)
DOSBox-X
DOSBox-Staging

If there are others, I haven't yet found them.
The last two are, as far as I've gathered, forks of the first. DOSBox-X is aiming for general purpose DOS emulation and not just games, whereas DOSBox-Staging seems to be games-first, apps-second.
I'm not sure what the actual differences are between DOSBox-X and DOSBox-Staging in terms of features provided or missing, or quality of emulation. They seem to behave more or less the same in the grand scheme of things, and I can't figure out where to look for a good comparison, or even how to make one; I'm ignoring features like a graphical config tool or shaders, as those are ultimately secondary to emulation itself, and instead want to compare them as emulators.
Due to using both of them for a bit, I do know that they behave differently (for example, I get relatively frequent mouse-related crashes in certain apps when using the newest Staging version, but DOSBox-X doesn't replicate this behaviour), I'm just not sure how to look at how deep it goes and where it might differ in important ways for myself.

DosBoxes are all modern software. You are asking to do a comparison between different instances of modern software, not retro software or retro hardware.

Yes, I'm asking for a comparison between modern emulator software used to emulate retro software and simulate retro hardware. If the question isn't a good fit for this SE, I apologise and will take suggestions as to where to re-ask it, but it felt fitting, and there's a dosbox tag, with at least one question asking about the modern software's functionality

It might be on topic, but I personally feel the retro aspect about the question is missing, as you are not revealing what the emulated DOS system must run and what does the DOS system expects to work in the emulator and in which way. It might be a better question if the question was not about just comparing emulators without any specific purpose in mind, but with a specific purpose in mind how they would suit for your purpose.

More problematically, they are moving targets (well, not so much the original DOSBox, but that may change at any time). The differences between those forks may vary from version to version, which may make answers obsolete.

@/Justme I'm planning to run a large suite of general software written between the late 80s and the late 90s from my university's software archives, including commercial general-purpose software and games from that period, and private university software that hasn't been published (yet?). I'm not sure what of that I could include to extend the question
@user3840170 would it help to add the release versions for each?

@mezenkur Then DosBox or any derived version may not suit your purposes at all, or only for the games. By default DosBox emulates a generic DOS enough to run games, not business critical or general purpose applications. If the applications expects to see some real DOS such as MS-DOS and specific version of it for some functionality, it's not going to work. Parallel ports are also not used for printer emulation, but for emulated DSS/Covox sound devices. You may need several different emulators and even a real DOS such as MS-DOS or FreeDOS.

Mezenkur - your "plan" in your last comment, should be edited into your question, as it clarifies your question, as to what you are aiming for. The version numbers might help, and might be useful to eliminate the "moving target". BTW, you can only address one person per comment, so user 3840170 will not receive a notification of your comment.

As of 2024 or so Dosbox-x has some features that might be required such as better post-2000 date handling and the ability to easily switch floppy images on the fly (required when you have to use a flux reader instead of a floppy controller to install multi-disk games).

Thing is, if you say you don't know how exactly you want these forks compared, how are we to know?

Those are all fair remarks and I will take them into account and update the question soon.

The DOSBox Staging project maintains a list of DOSBox forks with an indication of their level of development activity, if you want to look at others than the three you’ve listed (but really, these days DOSBox-X and DOSBox Staging are the only two really worth considering).
